# What is the technical part name of conical indent LEDs?

Tags: led

I'm struggling to find manufactures, part numbers or datasheets for the wide angle LEDs that have the conical indentation on the top of the lens. I found one other question on here that referred to them as dimple tip LEDs.

I have a prject that requires to use of wide angle LEDs that radiates light in all directions, perpendicular to the semi conductor. The conical indent in the lens of an LED would be perfect. These LEDs are extremley popular in modern festival/holiday LED light sets. In fact, I have not seen an LED set that does not use these LEDs. The problem is, I'm not able to find them anywhere. A search of the internet does not produce any usable results for this type of LED.

There are other wide angle LEDs out there, including "straw hat" and "flat top", but these types disperse the light in an arc. Round, or dome shaped LEDs project light almost perpendicular to the semi conductor.

If there was some type of part name, number or manufacturer of the conical LEDs, it mightn't be so hard to source them.

Apologies if this is off topic, but I'm out of options at this point.

Examples:

[image: Conical lens example 1]

[image: Conical lens example 2]

Comment: "flat top concave wide angle" or simply "concave led".

Comment: it utilises the critical angle (of the prism) to give total internal reflection as if the sides of the indent were mirrored (which they aren't)

Comment: I don't see this as off-topic. It would be if you were asking **where** to buy them. Ungortunately, I don't have a good answer for you.

Comment: Janka, thanks. This reassures me that I'm on the right path, but as pointed out in the question, a search using these term yields virtually no results. Hence why I'm asking to see if there's any other reference for these parts. JImDearden, again thanks for the comment. DoxyLover, no problem.Who would have thought it would be so difficult to identify what seem to be really common components?

Answer (score 1):

According to Lumex, in its Product Selection Guide 2004-1, Issue VII, the name is "T-5mm Dimple Lens". There's also a 3mm version, same name. Lumex handled this as SSL-LX507DT3 Series